# How do I save a figure from PyTorch using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using:

```
trainset = datasets.MNIST('saved/train', download=True,
                          train=True, transform=transform)

valset = datasets.MNIST('saved/test', download=True,
                        train=False, transform=transform)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
valloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)


dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()

fig = plt.figure()
print(images.shape)
print(labels.shape)

plt.plot(images[0].numpy().squeeze())

fig.savefig('figs/first.png')
```

However, this does not save the first image. It looks like:
[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [matplotlib.pyplot.imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html#matplotlib-pyplot-imshow) instead of `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`

```py
plt.imshow(images[0].numpy().squeeze())
fig.savefig('first_fig.png')
```

This will save matplotlib figure to save only image you can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.imsave`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20im#matplotlib-pyplot-imsave) like

```py
plt.imsave('first_imsave.png',images[0].numpy().squeeze())
```

or use [`torchvision.utils.save_image`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/utils.html#torchvision.utils.save_image)

```py
utils.save_image(images[0],'first_utils.png')
```